# Testing delete method in JUnit 5 with spring project get "Name for argument of type [long] not specified" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I'm quite new for spring and JUnit. Now I try to build a test case. after I run this one

```
  @Test
  public void shouldBeOK_Found() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/scores/{id}", 1L)
    ).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

I get this error trace.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [long] not specified, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
```

Here is my controller

```
  //Delete Score
  //DELETE /score/{id}
  @DeleteMapping("/scores/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Score> deleteScore(@PathVariable(required = true) long id) {
    Score result = null;
    try{
      Optional<ScoreEntity> s = scoreRepository.findById(id);
      if (s.isPresent()){
        result = new Score(s.get());
        scoreRepository.delete(s.get());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result);
      }
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
  }
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the name in the annotation if your code is not compiled with -parameter for Java 8 [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates).

> You can explicitly name URI variables (for example, @PathVariable("customId")), but you can leave that detail out if the names are the same and your code is compiled with debugging information or with the -parameters compiler flag on Java 8.

```
@PathVariable(required = true, name="id") long id
```